# Undo fast-forward merge without using hard reset

Tags: git, undo, fast-forward

I'm using git with Sourcetree. I've accidentally fast-forward merge and pushed to remote. Now I want to undo this. I know there is a way like this:

1. hard reset to commit before merge
2. force push to remote
3. remerge

But, i know that hard reset is dangerous. Is there any other way to do this? with steps included.

Thanks

Comment: Read the full answer attached above, will answer all your questions.

Comment: the answer is using hard reset..i don't want to use hard reset

Comment: @CodeWizard, This question is incorrectly marked as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/34519665/. This question asks for a solution that does not use reset which is what is the linked answer suggests.